# First-in first-out lines in a Text Field

Tags: delphi-5

I have a log file that I'd like to keep small.

I have a TDBListBox.

I have a stream of incoming data via the Serial Port.

```
procedure LogIt(tStr : String);
begin
  dm.tblLogs.Edit;
  dm.tblLogs.FieldByName(fldCommands).AsString:=
    dm.tblLogs.FieldByName(fldCommands).AsString+#10+tStr;
  dm.tblLogs.Post;
end;
```

This is working but the list is growing and I don't need more than about the last ten entries.

The only way I can think of doing this is to load the Field Data into a non-visible TMemo then

```
if Memo1.Lines.Count > 0 then
  Memo1.Lines.Delete(0);
```

Before adding the next line and then pass Memo.Lines.Text to the database Field.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `TStringList` instead of a `TMemo`.  But yes, you can maintain a separate list of log messages in memory, and then save only the latest 10 messages to the DB when the list is updated.  For example:

```
var
  log: TStringList;

...

log := TStringList.Create;
log.Capacity := 10;

...

procedure LogIt(tStr : String);
begin
  while log.Count >= 10 then
    log.Delete(0);
  log.Add(tStr);

  dm.tblLogs.Edit;
  try
    dm.tblLogs.FieldByName(fldCommands).AsString := log.Text;
    dm.tblLogs.Post;
  except
    dm.tblLogs.Cancel;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks Remy, that's a little kinder (using Try) than I had in mind, when I outlined the TMemo approach, it just seemed a little cumbersome, but the more I look at it, that's about as slick as it can get with the TStringList. I am displaying the text (AfterScroll) in a Tlistbox so I had to add the #10 as above. If I used #10#13, I get a blank line in the listbox.

Comment: Then you are not display the data in the ListBox correctly.  In any case, you might consider upgrading to a modern version of Delphi.  `TStrings` has had a `LineBreak` property for the past decade now (since at leat Delphi 2006 for sure, maybe even earlier).

Comment: Thanks, I bought 2005 in 2006 and have installed and uninstalled it many times. Hated it. D5-ent with GExperts etc is way more friendly. Also, may I ask that "not display .. correctly" is based on what? I am modifying some very old software and changing things for the sake of change is not very wise to assume.

Comment: @user2175495: The standard line break on Windows is `#13#10`, not `#10#13`. That would explain the extra lines that appear in your ListBox when using `#10#13`. Depending on how you are parsing the text, that mistake would easily generate 2 lines instead of 1.